# Force SQL Server to go through desired execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server Version : 2012

The stored procedure accepts a parameter `@personID`

The procedure is written this way:

```
select [some columns] 
from 
T1 join T2
on T1.id=T2.id
where
[condition 1]
and 
[condition 2]
and 
(
  @personid=10
  or 
  @personid<>10 and T1.addressID in 
                    ( select T3.addressID from 
                      T3 join T4 on T3.uid=T4.uid 
                      where [some conditions]
                    )
)
```

The Problem is :
SQL Server is executing the second half i.e `@personid<>10` and T1.* even when `personid=10`, which is causing unwanted reads and cpu time.

Is there any way like if/else, case statements to restrict it to not check the second half if first condition is met.

> EDIT:

I liked the answer of Vojtěch Dohnal (i.e using Option (Recompile) ) as well as answer of Rigerta Demiri (i.e use of if/else or separate stored procedures). I would say, that's a tie breaker.

**To all who are finding solution to similar problem:**
My suggestion is, if the Query's compile time is very short and is also not one of the frequently executed statements/procedures on production, then one should surely go with **Option (Recompile)**.

If it doesn't meet the aforesaid conditions then you should go with either if/else method or using two separate stored procedures.

Considering the fact that the select statement in my case has so many nested queries, its compile time isn't short and it is also one of the most frequently used procedures in production, so I have gone with creating two separate SPs, one for parameter match and one for otherwise.

Comment: Some related reading http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: The where condition don't have short circuit feature - it just depends to the execution plan. In your case you can use IF ELSE block as you defined exact value for different handling ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple case scenario for what is discussed and explained perfectly in this article by Kimberly L. Tripp [Building High Performance Stored Procedures](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/).

Other way is you can simply put your query inside an `IF-ELSE` block like this.

```
if @personId = 10
    begin

        select [some columns] 
        from 
        T1 join T2
        on T1.id=T2.id
        where
        [condition 1]
        and 
        [condition 2]
    end
else
    begin

        select [some columns] 
        from 
        T1 join T2
        on T1.id=T2.id
        where
        [condition 1]
        and 
        [condition 2]
        and 
         @personid<>10 and T1.addressID in 
                            ( select T3.addressID from 
                              T3 join T4 on T3.uid=T4.uid 
                              where [some conditions]
                            )
    end
```

OR, you could build the whole query dynamically and execute it as explained in the link.

Hope it helps!

> EDIT:

If what you really want is to have only one query execution plan evaluated when you are doing this branch logic, instead of both (as the query optimizer will do when executing the procedure) then you must separate it into two different sub-procedures and call them from a parent-wrapper-procedure.

This way, for each call you will only get one plan-optimized for the parameter.

I did something similiar here(with a different sample table called category) and got the following results:

```
create table category (category_no int identity(1,1) not null, category_desc varchar(100))
alter table [dbo].[category] add constraint [category_ident] primary key clustered ( [category_no] asc ) 

insert into category (category_desc) values ('test1', 'test2', 'test3')



create procedure testing_noparams
as
begin
    select * from category 
end

create procedure testing_withparams @categoryNo int 
as
begin
    select * from category where category_no = @categoryNo
end

create procedure wrapper @categoryNo int = null
as
begin

    if @categoryNo is null 
        begin
            exec testing_noparams
        end

    else
        begin
            exec testing_withparams @categoryNo
        end
end
```

Executing:

```
exec wrapper null
exec wrapper 2
```

The plans:

[image]

The problem with this approach is introducing a new procedure, but well :)

Comment: `and @personid<>10 and ...` and `and  @personid=10` will allways be true. No need for `option(recompile)` then.

Comment: Yes but try it, if you don't recompile for the second query that has "more" data to come, the generated plan will depend on whatever was in the cache before it. You might get the same plan as if the `@personId` was `10` (compiled for `@personId = 10`) unless you recompile. In this case maybe just using dynamic SQL would always get the best plan for the parameter value.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri I don't think it is true, if no parameter there should be no parameter sniffing issue to solve with `option(recompile)`

Comment: @Eric, There should not but it can happen, based on which plan has been first sent into the cache, or?

Comment: We are trying to say that if you write `if @personId = 10` then the condition `and  @personid=10` is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

To your query.

See [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#static).

> The effect of all the @x IS NULL clauses is that if an input parameter
>   is NULL, then the corresponding AND-condition is always true. Thus,
>   the only conditions that are in effect are those where the search
>   parameter has a non-NULL value. Sounds simple enough, but there is a
>   very big difference in performance with or without that last line
>   present:
>
> OPTION (RECOMPILE)
>
> The hint instructs SQL Server to recompile the query every time.
>   Without this hint, SQL Server produces a plan that will be cached and
>   reused. This has a very important implication: the plan must work with
>   all possible input values of the parameters. Due to parameter
>   sniffing, the plan may be optimised for the parameter combination for
>   the first search. That plan is likely to perform poorly with entirely
>   different parameters, while it still would not be perfect for the
>   initial parameter combination. For optimal response times when the
>   user provides a single order ID, we want the optimizer to use the
>   indexes on OrderID in Orders and Order Details and ignore everything
>   else. But if the user performs a search on a product ID or a product
>   name, we want to use the index on ProductID in Order Details and so on
>   for other search criterias.
>
> And this is exactly what we achieve with the hint OPTION (RECOMPILE).
>   Since SQL Server is instructed to recompile the query every time,
>   there is no need to cache the plan, why SQL Server **can handle all the
>   variables as constants.**

Note that this behavior works for sure on SQL Server 2012 and above, lower version [may have other older behaviors implemented](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#SPandCUs).

To see if this works check the Execution plan of your query - put it outside the stored procedure and check it as one separate query.

Comment: SQL Server gives me error "Incorrect syntax near 'Option' " in every case except the one in which I put it at the end of stored procedure, which is not a good hint as it is forcing it to recompile complete stored procedure and is degrading performance. Any suggestions.

Comment: Place it at the end of the SELECT query.

Comment: @BatMan Add `OPTION (RECOMPILE);` at the end of your SELECT query.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thanks. The problem is, the select statement in my case has so many nested queries, its compile time isn't short and it is also one of the most frequently used procedures in production, so I have gone with creating two separate SPs, one for parameter match and one for otherwise. I have used your suggestion and modified many other stored procedures. Thanks Vojtěch.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, the execution plan is irrelevant because the logic is incorrect. Perhaps the better solution is the link to Erland's discussion of dynamic searching - which requires additional complexity but might be beyond your needs / capabilities at this point.

If you properly parenthesize your conditions, you will solve your immediate logic problem. There are 3 conditions in your where clause. Your last condition consists of 2 different sub-conditions. Logically you have "and (x or y)" where y is also a set of 2 conditions. So We can expand that to "and (x or (y and z))". But there are no parentheses to indicate that z "goes with" y. In short, understand [logical operator precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: The execution plan is same with or without paranthesis around and operands set. To me it seems to be more of issue which @vojtěch-dohnal has suggested.